# prevent pandoc from adding a title when adding CSS to HTML using -H option

Tags: pandoc

I have an HTML file and I want to insert style information contained in `style6.css`.
Everything works fine except for that the page title gets inserted at the top of the HTML page and I cannot get rid of it.

**Before**: Starts with header

[image]

**After pandoc**: New style but title (which happens to be `Title` as well) is added on top

[image]

The command I used was `pandoc -s -H style6.css css_none.html -o css_new.html`.

How can I tell pandoc not to insert a title?

Answer (score 4):

Well, read the manual.

Finally figured it out myself. 
There is a template for each file format that is used when producing a standalone file. The template contains variables. If you set the `title` variable to an empty string adding `-V title:""` it seems to work.

So the total conversion is prompted as follows.
`pandoc -s -H style6.css -V title:"" css_none.html -o css_new.html`

If there is a better way please let me know!

Comment: yeah, but then the html will also have empty `<title></title>` inside `<head>`, which is not what you would typically want . From pandoc's man it seems that the variable `title-meta` should help, but it does not work (pandoc 2.11.1). From this [long thread](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4048) it turns out there is a hidden variable `pagetitle` that defines the `<title>` and saves the day!

Comment: @xealits Thanks! pagetitle did the trick. however, OP's solution also works, as in the `<title></title>` is filled with the specified title.

Comment: @SpackJarrow great! Also, `pagetitle` is mentioned in the [man page now](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/pull/6843), so there are more chances to notice it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with having an <h1> with your "title" at the top of the document, then just add this at the top of your document:

```
---
title: Your Title Here
---
```

If you want a different behaviour, then download and modify the default template for the output format as specified at https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates

Default templates are at https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates, download the one for your output format (eg: default.html5),or make pandoc generate it with `pandoc -D html5, modify it then run pandoc with the` --template=`option, or keep the default file name and use the`--data-dir=`option to point where your`default.html5` file is.